# Matching sections of text in regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, backreference

So I have a header where I can start matching text, then as for the end of the section, I used backreference for the header, to determine the end of a section:

sample data:

```
Section 1
sub-header here:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed interdum erat. Donec sed felis sit amet sem mattis aliquet non in turpis. 

sub-section with one newline above
option A
option B


sub-section 2 with two newline above
setting1: value of setting1
setting2: value of setting2


Section 2
sub-header here:
Nulla maximus mollis urna, in lobortis est auctor a. Ut erat enim, volutpat id tortor eget, elementum fermentum nisi.

sub-section with one newline above
option A
option B


sub-section 2 with two newline above
setting1: value of setting1
setting2: value of setting2


Section 3
sub-header here:
Sed suscipit eleifend arcu fringilla pulvinar. Maecenas ullamcorper efficitur fringilla.

sub-section with one newline above
option A
option B


sub-section 2 with two newline above
setting1: value of setting1
setting2: value of setting2
```

[Demo](https://regexr.com/3k8mj)

My regex looks like:

```
(?:^|\n)((Section\s*)(\d+))$([\s\S]*?)(?=\2)
```

This matches the first two sections but not the last section.

Comment: Replace `(?=\2)` with `(?=\2|$)`, but do not use `m` modifier, also remove `$` you have. See https://regexr.com/3k8n5

Comment: it won't select the 2nd section @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Right, there must be `\n` before `\2`, https://regex101.com/r/EN4rJO/1

Answer (score 3):

Try this Regex:

```
(Section\s*\d+)([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*Section\s*\d+|$)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mWMgVd/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(Section\s*\d+)` - matches the text `Section` followed by 0+ whitespaces followed by 1+ occurrences of a digit and captures the whole thing in group 1
- `([\s\S]*?)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character and captures it in group 2
- `(?=\s*Section\s*\d+|$)` - positive lookahead to make sure that whatever is matched above must either be followed by end of the string or by 0+ whitespaces followed by `Section` followed by 0+ whitespaces followed by 1+ digits

Comment: `((Section\s*)(\d+))([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*\2\d+|$)` can be simplified to that one i think.